# How to export beamer frames to standalone subfiles_

Tags: beamer, standalone

I try to split a large `beamer` presentation with the `standalone` suite. Herein, I do not want to split out parts of slides, for which I understand the `beamer` class option with the `standaloneframe` would be used, but whole series of slides with overlays and especially their own preambles. I ended up with these two files.

The main file

```
%main.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{title}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}
%\usepackage{standalone, tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\includestandalone{sub}
\end{document}
```

and a first part

```
% sub.tex
\documentclass[class=beamer,preview=false,crop=false,varwidth=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A Frame}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item an item
    \item another item
    \item a circle \tikz \draw circle (3pt);
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

`sub.tex` can be compiled as expected.

Compiling `main.tex` for the first time results in the title frame only followed by an empty slide. It suspect this is due to the collection of the preambles needing one run.

Compiling `main.tex` the second time leaves me with an error message which also occurs if I leave out the subpreambles to start with.

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.10 \end{frame}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The third run yields a slightly different message, which is repeated at all further `pdflatex` invocations.

```
Package currfile Warning: File stack underflow! on input line 259.

(./main.sta)
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.506   }
         %
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I've never used this package but according to the documentation, you need to use the standaloneframe environment rather than the frame environment in sub.tex. Have you tried that?

Comment: As far a I understand the documentation, `standaloneframe` is for content that will be placed *in* a frame and therefore has to drop its `frame` environment when compiled as a part of the main document. Nonetheless, I tried this, bit it did not make any difference.

Comment: That's not how I read it but I'm no expert. Also, it says to use the special beamer option rather than class=. However, I still can't get it to work. Two things seem to cause issues. The first is the use of the itemize environment. Nothing I do seems to get around this. The second is the use of the subpreambles option and nothing I do seems to get around that. If I dispense with itemize and include tikz rather than using the subpreambles option, I can get it to work, but that's hardly much help. However, it does seem there are two issues here so maybe creating separate MWE would help?